# Triggering jQuery on an opener window

Tags: jquery, window.opener

I am opening a dialog window from a main window.  The dialog is used to upload a file.  When it is complete, I want the dialog to trigger a jQuery function in the opener window.  Seems like this should work, but so far it's not.

in the main window I am opening the dialog like this:

```
jQuery('.modaldataupload').click(function() {
    var newwindow = window.open(jQuery(this).prop('href'), '', 'height=400,width=500,top=200,left=200');
    if (window.focus) {
        newwindow.focus();
    }
```

That works.  The upload takes place using php, that works, and the dialog is redirected to a confirmation page that has this in it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
jQuery('#datauploadslist', window.opener.document).val('hello');
});
</script>
```

In the main window, I have a div:

```
<div id="datauploadslist"></div>
```

Shouldn't I get "hello" in that div?

Answer (score 0):

Use `text()` instead of `val()` , `val()` set's the value of form-fields